# Javascript to modify current URL?

Tags: javascript, url

I am trying to write a javascript that detects if the current page contains a "?" in the url and, if it does, get everything in the url up to the "?" and then reload the window with this new url.  I've tried this:

```
var curr_url = window.location.toString();
if (curr_url.indexOf('?')!== -1){
    var goodpart = curr_url.split('?');
    //alert(goodpart[0]);
    window.location = goodpart[0];
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Either it does nothing for some pages or it works but keeps reloading the page over and over.

Comment: This should work, Is there any URL-rewriting active on serverside?

Comment: Agree with Dr.Molle, do you have any meta tags? AJAX? What do you mean it keeps reloading the page?  How are you implementing this?  Example site?

Comment: The reason it keeps re-loading the page is because when you change window.location, the browser will go and load that page. You keep getting caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate???

Answer (score 1):

```
if (location.search)
{
    location.href = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + location.pathname;
}
```

That should reload to the current URL minus any querystring.

Comment: You don't need the protocol and the host because they'll default to the current protocol and host anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.location.href=goodpart[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var new_url     = (window.location+'').replace(/\?.*/,'');
window.location = new_url;
```